# Spilt coke on my lenovo laptop any chance for it to get fixed?

Tags: laptop, water-damage

I spilled less than half a cup of coke on the right side of the keyboard.

- At first all the keys were working.
- Then, when clicking "w" it types "2" and some other keys stopped working.
- I dried every visible part that got coke on.
- I didn't know what to do, having never experienced this, so I didn't know I had to turn it off. Instead it was on the entire time.
- I tried to vacuum it and got some liquid out.
- Then the following hour it stopped working and today I sent it to service.

It is still under guarantee any chance that it can be fixed for free? If not could you tell me a possible price if it can even be fixed. What could be damaged and can I buy new parts?

I knew that I had to take out the battery but its really hard to open this laptop and I needed special instruments which I couldn't find at 12 am.

Comment: Can't say about the keyboard but what kind of laptop is it that needs special instruments to get a battery out ?

Comment: Its a lenovo im not sure about the model , but its like a gaming laptop bought it for mainly gaming. And on normal laptops its under the laptop ( the battery) but on mine it isnt there like there are 4 screws and i have to open them to find the battery i think.

Comment: He has non removable battery I guess.

Comment: Yep you could say that.

Comment: There's no way any guarantee will cover accidental damage - that's what insurance is for.

Comment: On the upside, Lenovos tend to be built in a rather modular fashion, with easy-to-replace parts. You are unlikely to need to pay for more than actually needs to be fixed or replaced.

Comment: Yes, I have done this coke thing to myself twice and one time Lenovo just popped the keyboard out and put it a new one. I was ashamed for the second time so spent time cleaning myself